# Thermal image based segmentation

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm working on a project to do segmentation of thermal images. So far, the methods have produced limited segmentation performance (k-means, Otsu's Method, Sobel, Canny, LoG).

I am trying to achieve good segmentation of doors and windows in images like these. What approaches would you suggest to try?

I have tried to convert the images to grayscale using the temperature map, but this has done little to improve segmentation accuracy of these regions of interest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably this could be of some help: [Finding squares in Image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/finding-squares-in-image)

Comment: Doors and windows are mostly squares (or rectanges) `;)`, with maybe embedded squares/rectanges embedded within.